# How to analyze larger texts in spaCy?

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

I would like to analyze larger chunks of text, preferably inside the xlsx or docx document. All I found was the doc = nlp('string'). When I tried to paste a really long string it no longer worked trigerring an ipython syntax error (Jupyter's issue I guess?), so my workaround didn't wor either.

What can I do if I would like to analyze something bigger, like, say 20 pages?
Also, can I integrate this code into scattertext somehow?

```
import spacy
import pl_core_news_sm

nlp = pl_core_news_sm.load()
doc = nlp("Kazik: Niegroźny wirus zasiał panikę. Ludzie dobrowolnie poddali się inwigilacji- Przetestowano, na ile ludzie dobrowolnie poddadzą się inwigilacji. To był bardzo dobry moment. Okazało się, że wystarczy nawet drobne hasło i są gotowi oddać swoją wolność.")

from spacy.lemmatizer import Lemmatizer
from spacy.lookups import Lookups
lookups = Lookups()
lookups.add_table("lemma_rules", {"noun": [["s", ""]]})
lemmatizer = Lemmatizer(lookups)

for token in doc:
    if (token.is_alpha == True and token.is_stop == False):
        print(token.lemma_)
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's this line of code `print(token.lemma_)` that crashes your jupyter kernel by the amount of info you're trying to print.

To avoid it cap the amount of info you're printing into your jupyter notebook by a meaningful number like:

```
for token in doc[:100]: # a cap
    if (token.is_alpha == True and token.is_stop == False):
        print(token.lemma_)
```

or assign your output to a list:

```
lst = []
for token in doc:
    if (token.is_alpha == True and token.is_stop == False):
        lst.append(token.lemma_)
```

Comment: @Poodle1860  Does it answer your question? Was it helpful? Please consider https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers